# How to validate data only after button click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to validate inputs only after a submit button is clicked. However, the required rule is activating after focus lost. I'm using VeeValidate in Vue.js.

HTML:

```
<input 
  name="Email" 
  v-validate 
  data-vv-rules="required|email" 
  id="email" 
  type="email" 
  v-model="email" 
  placeholder="Email " 
>
```

JS:

```
this.$validator.validateAll().then(success => {

})
```

Comment: could you post ur full js function ..

Comment: From a UX standpoint, instant feedback after losing focus gives the form a nice interactive feel to it. This isn't the most helpful for the question but it's useful to be said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`data-vv-validate-on`](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/api.html#data-attributes) to disable the default validation behavior like so: `data-vv-validate-on="none"`

Then add a click event handler to your submit button a `@click="submit"`.

And the `submit` method for your component would look something like this:

```
methods: {
  submit() {
    this.$validator.validateAll().then(success => {
      // submit the value
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: now input is validating on click on it, i need to validate on button submit click

Comment: I founded unswer: `data-vv-validate-on="none"` works perfect, ty

Answer (score 0):

If your version of vee-validate < 4, [this](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/interaction-and-ux.html) might help